# DataBinding fails for a collection property of custom control

Tags: wpf, data-binding, custom-controls

I have a user control - say "ControlBase". It has "SomeItems" property, which is an `ObservableCollection<InheritedFromDO>`, where `InheritedFromDO` is a class inherited from "DependencyObject".
When I create markup for a child class of the `ControlBase` i'd like to initiate the "SomeItems" collection. But somehow I cannot use bindings in that markup, although the control has a pretty normal DataContext and binding works in normal cases.

It looks like this:

```
<local:ControlBase
   ...
   >
   <local:ControlBase.SomeItems>
     <SomeItem
       DepPropertyOne={Binding Id} <!-- Does NOT work here -->
       />
     <SomeItem
       DepPropertyOne={Binding Name} <!-- Does NOT work here -->
       />
   <local:ControlBase.SomeItems>

   <Grid>
     <TextBlock
       Text={Binding Id} <!-- Works here -->
       />
   </Grid>
</local:ControlBase>
```

The output says:

`System.Windows.Data Error: 2 : Cannot find governing FrameworkElement or FrameworkContentElement for target element. BindingExpression:Path=Id; DataItem=null; target element is 'SomeItem' (HashCode=26965808); target property is 'DepPropertyOne' (type 'Object')`

Any ideas how to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the items in the collection are not part of the logical tree. You need to [customize the logical children](http://kentb.blogspot.com/2008/10/customizing-logical-children.html) of your control if you want that to work, or subclass a control that does it for you (eg. [`ItemsControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.aspx)).

Comment: Thanks Kent, that's exactly what i needed. It also seems to resolve some issues i had with Resources resolution

Comment: although, it still works properly only if objects are inherited from  FrameworkElement, not just DependencyObject